# I need to capture a notification

Tags: android

I need to know when a notification is created because I want to change the audio mode. Is possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listening for Notification on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361148/listening-for-notification-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Android 4.3 it **is** possible to get Notifications within a third-party app.
See [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) class, However an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361148/listening-for-notification-on-android) on SO, suggests that

***There is currently no generic way to intercept Notifications sent from other applications.***

However if you want to listen something like SMS notifications than [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing) can be useful for you..

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to capture whatssapp notifications to change the audio mode but I see that is impossible.